# Unable to access CRAN repository on windows10 with multiple R versions

Tags: r, installation, warnings, cran

I am no longer able to install packages for R 3.6.1 (64bit) using CRAN.  I have been installing packages on my Windows10 system with CRAN and Rtools 3.5 for years with this R version without any trouble. I think the problem occured after installing R 4.3.0 and Rtools 4.3 on my system.  With the same system, when I switch to R 4.3.0 in Rstudio I can install new packages from CRAN without any problem.  I uninstalled R 3.6.1, deleted the library paths and reinstalled R 3.6.1 but the problem is still there:

> Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
> cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'

I have seen a couple of similar problems on stackoverflow but none of the solutions work:

[Try disabling “secure download method for HTTP”](https://community.rstudio.com/t/install-packages-unable-to-access-index-for-repository-try-disabling-secure-download-method-for-http/16578)

[Change CRAN repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72619247/warning-in-install-packages-unable-to-access-index-for-repository)

When running code:

```
browseURL("https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES")
```

a web page opens up in my browser with a list of available packages
[image: CRAN link]

When running code:

```
getOption("repos")
```

I get the following response:

```
                       CRAN 
"https://cran.rstudio.com/" 
attr(,"RStudio")
[1] TRUE
```

When running code:

```
install.packages("ggplot2", repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")
```

I get the following response:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/userName/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘ggplot2’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.6:
  cannot open URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/PACKAGES'
```

Here is some session info after re-installing R 3.6.1:

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_Canada.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_Canada.1252    LC_MONETARY=French_Canada.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=French_Canada.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.1 tools_3.6.1
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60597302/installing-old-package-version-on-old-r-version 

There are probably new minimum versions of R for those packages because of important changes in R. You would have to access older versions of the packages as described in that question.

Comment: Reasonable guess, but as I say in my answer below (which should probably be a comment but too long ...), at least `ggplot2` is OK, and "unable to access index" suggests a network problem rather than a missing-package problem ...

Comment: Are you on a work network or something that requires a proxy server? It's possible those settings were lost when you uninstalled the old R version. Are you using RStudio or just R directly?

Comment: I'm using RStudio.  No work network.  And switching to R4.3 in RStudio makes the problem disappear (for R4.3)!?!

Answer (score 1):

The mirror you're trying in the latter code block doesn't seem to exist: the [CRAN mirror list](https://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html) lists three Canadian mirrors, one of which is `https://mirror.rcg.sfu.ca/mirror/CRAN/` (the `.sfu.ca` mirror you tried must be defunct).  On the other hand, the RStudio mirror (which you're pointing to when you get the `https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib` error) seems to be fine and have a 3.6 directory, see [here](https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/).

What does

```r
install.packages("ggplot2", repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")
```

get you? What is `getOption("repos")` ?

To test for generic network problems, try

```r
browseURL("https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES")
```

(Another reason for failing package installs would be a package that requires a newer version of R, but the [ggplot2 CRAN page](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=ggplot2) says that R >= 3.3 should be fine.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I edited my question to address your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You should also try installing packages through the R application instead of inside RStudio.